# What is the "noautoscale" in pgfpages in LaTeX?

Tags: pdfpages

In `pdfpages` package, there are `noautoscale` and `fitpaper` options and so on. I understand what the `fitpaper` means. But what does `noautocale` mean? What does the `noautoscale` scale to? I have done a test, in which `noautoscale=true` and `noautoscale=false` have a little difference, but I can't tell which cause this difference.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    paper=b5paper,
}
\begin{document}

\includepdf[noautoscale=true]{1.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sample code for your test?

Comment: @cfr I updated the question. But you don't have that pdf file.

Comment: So use a PDF file we *do* have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following pictures should explain it.

```
% test1.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\pagecolor{blue}

\begin{document}
        Inner doc
\end{document}
```

and

```
% test2.tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\includepdf[noautoscale=true]{test1}

\includepdf[noautoscale=false]{test1}

\end{document}
```

yield (left is page 1, right is page 2)

[image]

---

Since the OP asked a followup about `fitpaper`, check out

```
% test3.tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\includepdf[noautoscale=true]{test1}

\includepdf[fitpaper=true]{test1}

\end{document}
```

Displaying the two pages at the same magnification, you see that page 1 has size A4, with a size A5 inner document displayed at its original size. Page 2 on the other hand has the paper itself trimmed to be size A5.

[image]

Comment: In case it isn't clear: `noautoscale=true` includes the pdf in the original size. `noautoscale=false` scales the pages down to the document page size. (Here the inner document was made on A5 and the outer is on A4.)

Comment: But, this should be the `fitpage` option. Are these two options same?

Comment: @Y.zeng The `fitpaper` option changes the page size of the **outer** document to fit the page size of the inner document.

Comment: @Y.zeng There is no such option in `pdfpages`.

Comment: @cfr Thanks. It should be `fitpaper`.